# Deploy with gitlab-runner and docker

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying deploy nodejs app and I use this [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-auto-deploy-a-vue-application-using-gitlab-ci-cd-on-ubuntu/),
so my `.gitlab-ci.yml` is looks like

```
image: docker
services:
  - docker:dind
stages:
  - deploy
step-deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker build -t app/vue-demo .
    - docker run -d -p 80:80 --rm --name todoapp app/vue-demo
```

and Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

this config works fine and docker container still alive after deploy 
but for my app I need start `npm run start` command so I changed Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as production-stage
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["npm", "run", "start;"]
```

job passed but docker conatiner is closed after deploy 
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your second stage there is no files unless you specifically copy them. In your scenario you don't even need 2 stages for build. This should work:

```sh
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```